# Unicode transform in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I want to transform the string in a dict to Chinese, but do not know how. Some hints would be helpful for me.

> My python version is 2.7.12 on win32

First of all, I have variable s

```
s = '\u7279\u6717\u666e\u5973\u513f\u4f0a\u4e07\u5361\u5230\u4e2d\u56fd\u5927\u4f7f\u9986\u8d3a\u65b0\u5e74'
```

And it works when I used these 2 methods: Bo

```
print u'\u7279\u6717\u666e\u5973\u513f\u4f0a\u4e07\u5361\u5230\u4e2d\u56fd\u5927\u4f7f\u9986\u8d3a\u65b0\u5e74'
```

Output : 特朗普女儿伊万卡到中国大使馆贺新年

```
print eval("u'%s'" %s)
```

Output : 特朗普女儿伊万卡到中国大使馆贺新年

But when I have a dict called data, and print it as the following.

```
data = {
'title' : s,
}
print data
```

The output shows up like

> {'title': '\u7279\u6717\u666e\u5973\u513f\u4f0a\u4e07\u5361\u5230\u4e2d\u56fd\u5927\u4f7f\u9986\u8d3a\u65b0\u5e74'}

Comment: Where did you get `s`?

Comment: Where are you running it? Does (Terminal, PowerShell, ..) it support chinese chracters?

Comment: I ran it in the Pycharm

Comment: Seems that I could not print the correct **data**, but could only print the s directly. Question is how to interpret the content in a dict or a list if Chinese characters are contained.

Answer (score 0):

You can decode a string into Chinese using using `unicode escape`

**In Python 3.x**

```
s = b'\u7279\u6717\u666e\u5973\u513f\u4f0a\u4e07\u5361\u5230\u4e2d\u56fd\u5927\u4f7f\u9986\u8d3a\u65b0\u5e74'
```

notice the b - byte literal

> ```
> print(s.decode('unicode-escape'))
> 特朗普女儿伊万卡到中国大使馆贺新年
> ```

**In Python 2.x**

```
print s.decode('unicode-escape')
特朗普女儿伊万卡到中国大使馆贺新年
```

Edited:
In your case, since you are using python 2.7:

```
s = u'\u7279\u6717\u666e\u5973\u513f\u4f0a\u4e07\u5361\u5230\u4e2d\u56fd\u5927\u4f7f\u9986\u8d3a\u65b0\u5e74'
```

notice the use of 'u'- unicode literal.

now if you want to print it just type `print s`, print acts as an encoder

and if you want to use it inside a dictionary, just use s, because ultimately it will be stored as a unicode string and whenever you want to see the result just print the value.

Comment: One learns something new everyday - first time I read about `unicode-escape`) and I cant' even find it with the builtin search on Python2.x doc.... But it indeed do the job (on 2.7.6).

Comment: yes you are correct, you can't even find it in builtin search.. but these unicodes strings were always a headache.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But how can I print the data as expected?

Comment: when you assign key value pairs in your dictionary, just decode the 's' value using unicode-escape.
in your case:
`data = {'title': s.decode('unicode-escape')}`

Comment: Hi still now working using `data = {'title': s.decode('unicode-escape')}`.

Comment: It prints out `{'title': u'\u7279\u6717\u666e\u5973\u513f\u4f0a\u4e07\u5361\u5230\u4e2d\u56fd\u5927\u4f7f\u9986\u8d3a\u65b0\u5e74'}`

Comment: try this:
`print '\u7279\u6717\u666e\u5973\u513f\u4f0a\u4e07\u5361\u5230\u4e2d\u56fd\u5927\u4f7f\u9986\u8d3a\u65b0\u5e74'.decode('unicode-escape')
`

Comment: Thanks. I know how to print the string. But what if I want to print the dict or a list with the string contained?

Answer (score 0):

First point : `print data` prints the inner representation of the your `data` dict (the result of `repr(data)`), so you get the inner representation of your string.  You'll notice the same behaviour with `print repr(s)` vs `print s`.

Also, if you want to use unicode strings, you have to explicitely tell Python it's a unicode string by prefixing the string litteral with a 'u', ie:

```
s = u'\u7279\u6717\u666e\u5973\u513f\u4f0a\u4e07\u5361\u5230\u4e2d\u56fd\u5927\u4f7f\u9986\u8d3a\u65b0\u5e74'
print s
```

This won't make your `print data` work as you seem to expect but at least you can properly print your unicode string either as is or by encoding it to the desired encoding.

NB : if your Python version is recent enough you can also start your script with from `__future__ import unicode_literals` which will tell Python to treat each and any literal string in this module as a unicode string.

NB2: if you get your `s` string from an external resource then there's something wrong in the way - since what you get is a byte string containing unicode points -, so first fix this issue (you should get either a properly encode byte string - in a known encoding - or preferably a proper unicode string).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got my s string from crawling the data using "beautifulsoup" and "request" from "http://news.qq.com/" which encodes in "gb2312".

Answer (score 0):

You can use pprint. Here is the quora answer that 
answers your questiion. Ran it in idle to view the uncode string correctly

https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-print-a-python-unicode-data-structure

```
import pprint
_escape = dict((q, dict((c, unicode(repr(chr(c)))[1:-1])
                        for c in range(32) + [ord('\\')] +
                        range(128, 161),
                        **{ord(q): u'\\' + q}))
               for q in ["'", '"'])
class MyPrettyPrinter(pprint.PrettyPrinter):
    def format(self, object, context, maxlevels, level):
        if type(object) is unicode:
            q = "'" if "'" not in object or '"' in object \
                else '"'
            return ("u" + q + object.translate(_escape[q]) +
                    q, True, False)
        return pprint.PrettyPrinter.format(
            self, object, context, maxlevels, level)


pp = MyPrettyPrinter()
s = u'\u7279\u6717\u666e\u5973\u513f\u4f0a\u4e07\u5361\u5230\u4e2d\u56fd\u5927\u4f7f\u9986\u8d3a\u65b0\u5e74'
print(s)
data = {
u'title' : s 
}
pp.pprint(data)
```